# How to rename the rows in dataframe using pandas read (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, rows

I want to rename rows in python program (version - `spyder 3` - `python 3.6`) . At this point I have something like that:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(filepath, delim_whitespace = True, header = None)
```

Before that i wanted to rename my columns:

```
data.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

It gave me something like that.

```
    A   B   C  
0   1   n   1  
1   1   H   0  
2   2   He  1  
3   3   Be  2
```

But now, I want to rename rows. I want:

```
     A   B   C  
n    1   n   1  
H    1   H   0  
He   2   He  1  
Be   3   Be  2
```

How can I do it? The main idea is to rename every row created by `pd.read` by the data in the B column. I tried something like this:

```
for rows in data:
    data.rename(index={0:'df.loc(index, 'B')', 1:'one'})
```

but it's not working.

Any ideas? Maybe just replace the data frame rows by column B? How?

Comment: Adding an index (with correct naming) and removing the old one does not help?

Comment: It might help if i know how to exactly write the code :/ - but the problem is solved below very nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('B', drop=False).rename_axis(None)
```

Solution with `rename` and dictionary:

```
df1 = df.rename(dict(zip(df.index, df['B'])))

print (dict(zip(df.index, df['B'])))
{0: 'n', 1: 'H', 2: 'He', 3: 'Be'}
```

If default `RangeIndex` solution should be:

```
df1 = df.rename(dict(enumerate(df['B'])))

print (dict(enumerate(df['B'])))
{0: 'n', 1: 'H', 2: 'He', 3: 'Be'}
```

**Output**:

```
print (df1)
    A   B  C
n   1   n  1
H   1   H  0
He  2  He  1
Be  3  Be  2
```

EDIT:

If dont want column `B` solution is with [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) by parameter `index_col`:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""1 n 1
1 H 0
2 He 1
3 Be 2"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), delim_whitespace=True, header=None, index_col=[1])
print (df)
    0  2
1       
n   1  1
H   1  0
He  2  1
Be  3  2
```

Comment: Wonderful!! Thank you a lot :)

I used the

    _df1 = df.set_index('B', drop=False).rename_axis(None)_

and it worked nicely! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I normally rename my rows in my dataset by following these steps.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("zzzz.csv")


#in a dataframe it is hard to change the names of our rows so,
df.transpose()

#this changes all the rows to columns

df.columns=["","",.....]
# make sure the length of this and the length of columns are same ie dont skip any names.

#Once you are done renaming them: 

df.transpose()

#We get our original dataset with changed row names.
```

Answer (score 0):

just put colnames into `"names"` when reading

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', names=["colname A", "colname B"])
```